# VirtualBox state suddenly SEEMs to have been restored to an earlier time

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have CentOS 7 installed on my Windows 8.1 VirtualBox, and file-system sized 30Gb.

It worked fine until this morning, then the storage became full (due to Downloads and Projects). I tried a tool called CloneVDI to clone the content of my HDD `.vdi` file into a large file-system (60Gb).

Now when I launch the Linux with any of the `.vdi` (the old or the new), it launches, gets run, I log in, but I see its state seems to have been restored to an earlier time ( many of my downloads and files have disappeared ).

Comment: Were you using virtualbox snapshots?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes I was and it seems it has been dragged back to the snapshot...is there any solution?

Comment: CloneVDI can optionally include snapshots. It ought to have saved the original vdi in "Original <name>.vdi".